# Using JQ to get simple delimited output

Tags: json, jq

How might one turn this:

```
{
  "write": {
    "out": 0,
    "available": 128,
    "totalTickets": 128
  },
  "read": {
    "out": 7,
    "available": 249,
    "totalTickets": 256
  }
}
```

Into

```
0 128 128 7 249 256
```

Using jq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also recursively descend your JSON tree like that:

```bash
>jq 'recurse|numbers' data.json
0
128
128
7
249
256
```

(this assumes that all your values are *numbers*, use *scalars* if you also want booleans and strings)

Or use a shorthand notation for *recurse*, which is `..`

```bash
..|numbers
```

(Thanks @cuonglm !)

Note, that unlike *map|flatten* approach this will also work for an arbitrary nested tree of objects.

E.g.

```json
{
  "write": {
    "out": 0,
    "available": 128,
    "totalTickets": 128
  },
  "read": {
    "out": 7,
    "available": 249,
    "totalTickets": 256,
    "details" : {
        "good": 10,
        "bad" : 20
    }
  }
}
```

will produce:

```
0
128
128
7
249
256
10
20
```

Comment: or shorter `jq '..|numbers'`

Comment: Dang that's neat...

Comment: With the slight modifier of
command | jq -r 'recurse|numbers' | paste -s
this did exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ jq 'map(map(values))|flatten|.[]' data.json
0
128
128
7
249
256
```

The first part generates

```
[
  [
    0,
    128,
    128
  ],
  [
    7,
    249,
    256
  ]
]
```

This is flattened into:

```
[
  0,
  128,
  128,
  7,
  249,
  256
]
```

And the `.[]` extracts those values.